# Há uma forma de atualizar o PHP dentro do HTML sem ter que recarregar a pagina?

Tags: php, html5, api

Há uma forma de atualizar o PHP dentro do HTML sem ter que recarregar a pagina HTML ? Tenho uma pagina que mostra o tempo de resposta de uma API mas para que o tempo de respostas possa ser atualizado frequentemente eu uso o codigo HTML:

```
< meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=index.php" />
```

Há alguma forma de faze isso em php ? , se por acaso não entendem o site https://steamgaug.es/ faz exatamente oque estou tentando explicar

PS - Não sei se este site utiliza PHP.

Comment: sim, de uma pesquisada sobre Ajax

Comment: Você pode fazer isto com Ajax, utilizando do elemento SetTimeOut